# What is the big-o of the function 2log(log(n)) + 3nlog(n) + 5log(n)?

Tags: big-o

What is the big-o of the function 2log(log(n)) + 3nlog(n) + 5log(n)?

Is is just O(nlog(n)) for the whole function? I'm not sure how to represent 2log(log(n)).

Comment: If that's the equation, it's O(1) since complexity shouldn't be dependant upon what `n` is.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/ would be best suited for this question

Comment: log(log n) is just log(log n); it is a lower order than log(n) in the same way that log(n) is smaller than n.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are being asked to find the big-o of a function that, for an input of size n, performs 2log(log(n)) + 3nlog(n) + 5log(n) operations.

If this is indeed the case, than your assumption is right that the big-o is O(nlog(n)), as that is the largest term in the amount of operations, and big-o disregards constants.

O(log(log(n))) is its own separate time class, and is faster than O(log n). To reason about O(log(log(n))), consider that O(log(n)) is considered substantially faster than O(n), so it stands to reason that O(log(log(n))) is substantially faster than O(log(n)).